# Project facet WebSphere Web (Co-existence) version 8.0 is not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, websphere, websphere-liberty

I have been tasked with working on a web portal application at work.

I have been given a pre-existing copy of project folders from eclipse.  I am unable to get it to run.

I am trying to setup a local server and do the development locally, then move it to the production server.

For my server I have setup WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Liberty Profile.  I created a "Hello World" project to make sure that it is working.  It is.

When I try to right click the project and select Run As -> Run on Server... I see the following:

[image: Run On Server]

I'm not sure if this helps, but here are Project Facets:
[image: Project Facets]

Current software:

- Eclipse, Java EE IDE, Kepler, Release 4.3.2
- WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 Liberty Profile
- Java Compiler 1.7 (1.6, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can safely uncheck both WebSphere Co-existence and Extended project facets. This will allow you to deploy to Liberty from Eclipse.

Comment: Worked for me ! 
Very nice !